# Linq-to-Sql filtering for dates of last element

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
FruitID | BasketID | HarvestDate
  10    |    435   |   10/1/2014
  11    |    430   |   8/4/2014
  12    |    435   |   3/1/2014
  13    |    430   |   5/2/2014
```

I want to pass in a list of BasketIDs and return only the BasketID where all the HarvestDate are less than a certain date. For instance, if I pass in 430 and 435 and for the data Sep 29 then the query should return only 430 because 435 has Fruit 10 that has a HarvestDate past the parameter.

This is what I have:

```
var Output = (from f in MyDC.Fruits
              where TheBasketIDs.Contains(f.BasketID) &&
                 f.HarvestDate <= TheDate
              select f.BasketID).ToList();
```

My instinct tells me I should group by BasketIDs that match IDs passed in and then sort by HarvestDate and take the BasketIDs where the last date is less than the date parameter but I'm stuck on the syntax. How can I fix this query?

Comment: What makes you think you need to "fix" the query? Have you tried the query you've already got?

Comment: Yes, this is the query I have and the problem is that it's returning both 430 and 435 when I pass in the date 9/29. It shouldn't return 435 because that basket has also has a harvest date of 10/1. The query works in the sense that it doesn't bug but it doesn't return the expected value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(from f in MyDc.Fruits
group f by f.BasketID into g
where TheBasketIDs.Contains(g.Key)
&& g.OrderByDescending(gg=>gg.HarvestDate).First().HarvestDate <= TheDate
select g.First().BasketID).ToList();
```

Comment: The query should end with .ToList() since we're returning a list of BasketIDs. I'm still working on it using the groupby and where clause you have. I tried the select with select g.Select(x => x.BasketID).ToList(); but it's not working (yet)

Comment: Ok, saw the edit: removed the ordering filter in the select and this compiles: select g.First().LeadID and then I wrap the entire query with a (.....).ToList() like you have in the edit. We'll know in a few minutes.

Comment: NP, yeah the ordering is redundant if you only need the Id. Will edit it out.

Answer (score 2):

Make the opposite.

Select all those which have harvest day greater than the **HarvestDate** and than make your query and those which were returned in the first query should be eliminated.

```
var Output1 = (from f in MyDC.Fruits
              where TheBasketIDs.Contains(f.BasketID) &&
                 f.HarvestDate > TheDate
              select f.BasketID).ToList();

var Output2 = (from f in MyDC.Fruits
          where TheBasketIDs.Contains(f.BasketID) &&
             f.HarvestDate <= TheDate
          select f.BasketID).ToList();

var Output = Output2.Except(Output1).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm blushing here... tnx :)

Comment: Don't you have to provide some custom compararer?

Comment: I think for integer that works out of the box. But even so, the principal and simplicity are my guide. Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice you're selecting only the Id.